# css: hover on the span in li tag

Tags: css

what is wrong with my code? why when i hover on  tag, don't change background in  tag.

```
<style type="text/css">
#menu ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-left: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    height: 33px;
}
#menu li{
    display: inline;
    margin-left: 5px;
    height: 33px;
}
#menu a{
    color: #336699;
    height: 33px;   
}
#menu a:hover{
    color: #FFFFFF;
    height: 33px;
    background:url(images/mid.gif);
}
#menu li .right{
    width: 20px;
}
#menu li .right:hover{
    width: 20px;
    background:url(images/right.png) no-repeat;
    background-position: left top;
}
</style>
<body>
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href = "">One<span class="right"></span></a></li>
        <li><a href = "">Two<span class="right"></span></a></li>
        <li><a href = "">Three<span class="right"></span></a></li>
        <li><a href = "">Four<span class="right"></span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: probably because a overlays span?

Comment: a live example at jsbin.com would help more

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you are asking about the spans, they are inline elements so you cannot give the a width..

you need to use block elements (*like the `div` tag*) , or change the spans to become block with `display:block` or `display:inline-block`.

For more reading have a look at [W3C Visual Formatting Model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#display-prop), and also have a look at http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html#t03

---

You should also add an `&nbsp;` inside the spans so they get a height as well..

here is a live example http://jsfiddle.net/YuJPg/

Comment: what is the difference between block and inline-block?

Comment: @Collin, added some references that explain the differences.

Answer (score 0):

Change class .right to include `display: block;`